# Loop Through Directory VBA to Copy Data With Format

Tags: vba, excel

I have few files in a directory or a folder and I want to copy a range (values with format to the current sheet). I have VBA code and I think it is not in order or something is missing in the code. Please help me to fix the issue.

(I have defined named range in each files in the directory. Is it is possible to copy using the named range?)

Copy from directory files given path & from sheet2 & paste it to file "workbook.xlsm" Sheet "sheet1"

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    Dim Filepath As String
    Filepath = "C:\test"
    MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile = "workbook.xlsm" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A1:N24").Copy
        Workbooks.Open ("Filepath & workbook.xlsm")

        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = vbNullString Then
           Sheets("Sheet1").Range ("A1:N24")
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Else
            Selection.Copy Sheets("sheet1").Cells(A1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)                   
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Okay so first of all what happens when you run it?

Comment: Yes, what @KKowalczyk said. What it does do in comparison to what is supposed to happen is very helpful. I happen to have seen this enough to be have been able to spot it quickly.

Comment: I haven't checked your full code - but this line will not work:
`Workbooks.Open ("Filepath & workbook.xlsm")`.  You need to use `Workbooks.Open (Filepath & "\workbook.xlsm")`  - note I've added a '\' to the workbook name as the Filepath doesn't include it.

Comment: Also - you're opening `Workbooks.Open ("Filepath & workbook.xlsm")` and `Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)` on each pass of the loop.

If **workbook.xlsm** is the file you're pasting everything into then open it before entering the loop - you'll need to reference this workbook as it won't be the active workbook when you're pasting.

Comment: Also exiting sub when meeting workbook.xlsm may kill your loop before processing through half of files, better just skip the file instead

Comment: (all other files are *.xlsm & the sheet 2  range A1:A24 is generated automatically through a  vba  using named range  as reference. Thank u all..

Answer (score 1):

One question remains:

> (I have defined named range in each files in the directory. Is it is possible to copy using the named range?)

It's certainly possible. Thus assuming the `Defined Name` range is `"DATA"`.
Just replace this line:

```
sourceWbk.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:N24").Copy
```

with this:

```
sourceWbk.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("DATA").Copy
```

Actually, OP mentioned that this `Names` are generated by another procedure with the address `"A1:N24"`. So in the case that the address is changed then there will be a need to update every other procedure that refers to it, instead by using the `Defined Name` don't have to worry about it as it will be taking care by design. That why it’s a good practice to use `Defined Names`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this method:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim wrkbkSource As Workbook
    Dim wrkbkTarget As Workbook
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    FilePath = "C:\test\"
    MyFile = "workbook.xlsm"

    Set colFiles = New Collection

    EnumerateFiles FilePath, "*.xlsm", colFiles

    Set wrkbkTarget = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & MyFile)

    For Each vFile In colFiles
        If vFile <> FilePath & MyFile Then

            Set wrkbkSource = Workbooks.Open(vFile, False)
            wrkbkSource.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:N24").Copy

            Set rngTarget = wrkbkTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, wrkbkTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
            rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            wrkbkSource.Close False

        End If
    Next vFile

End Sub
```

This procedure is needed to get all the files in the folder:

```
Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef cCollection As Collection)

    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        cCollection.Add sDirectory & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay see if it works for you, had to add quite a bit

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Dim targetWbk As Workbook
Dim sourceWbk As Workbook

Filepath = "C:\test"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & "\workbook.xlsm")
Set sourceWbk = ActiveWorkbook


Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If Not MyFile = "workbook.xlsm" And MyFile = "*.xls*" Then

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
Set sourceWbk = ActiveWorkbook

sourceWbk.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:N24").Copy

If targetWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = vbNullString Then
targetWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:N24").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas, xlPasteValues

Else
 targetWbk.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(A1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas, xlPasteValues
End If

MyFile = Dir

End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You could change `MyFile = "*.xls" Or .....` to `MyFile = "*.xls*"` to capture all xls type files.

Comment: (all other files are *.xlsm) Thanks all of u for your reply.. I will go through it..